# Qual é a maior palavra no Português que não tenha nenhuma letra repetida?

Tags: vocabulário

Vi isso no Puzzling (em Inglês) e gostaria de saber qual seria a maior palavra sem nenhuma letra repetida em Português.

Link: [Longest word in English without repeated letter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/17667)

**REGRAS:**

> Não valem palavras que não estejam no dicionário;
>
> Ganha a palavra com mais letras;
>
> Em caso de empate, ganha quem tiver respondido primeiro;

Comment: É, a pergunta faz mais sentido num contexto de *puzzling* do que de estudo da língua. Não estou votando pra fechar, mas pra mim a pergunta está bem no limite do que seria on-topic aqui.

Comment: Poxa, não tem nenhum Puzzling PT pra eu perguntar isso ;-;

Comment: Vou já pensar em mais palavras :-) Não é melhor definires as regras? Nomeadamente contam diminuitivos? Como expurgadinho, que quase de certeza não vem em dicionário nenhum, como a maioria dos diminuitivos? E como se resolvem empates? Ganha quem respondeu primeiro? Divide-se o bounty por todas as palavras empatadas?

Comment: Ou ainda palavras formadas por aposição do prefixo de negação _in_ ou o prefixo _des_ mas que não venham no dicionário. Valem?

Comment: Pronto, editei pra ficar mais explicado... To bem ansioso pra saber essa resposta, um cara do Puzzling fez uma espécie de software para localizar essa palavra no Inglês o-o

Comment: Eu vi isso. Eu tenho conhecimentos de programação limitados, mas deve haver imensa gente aqui que consiga fazer isso. Mais uma dúvida: flexões de verbos em qualquer pessoa e qualquer tempo contam? No dicionário só vem o infinitivo. E os plurais e femininos também contam, suponho? No dicionário, normalmente, só vem o singular masculino.

Comment: Parece que só você ta querendo a bounty o-o Acho que vou acabar completando seus 1000!

Comment: PERNAMBUCO 10 letras usado pelos meus professôres para dar notas secretas (código PERNAMBUCO) O "P" valia nota 1 e o "O" valia nota 10.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Já que a pergunta permaneceu aberta, resolvi tentar. Também fiz um programinha pra procurar a resposta. Usei uma lista de palavras (http://www.winedt.org/Dict/) e fiz a busca pelas maiores palavras sem letras repetidas.

Fiz filtros para evitar problemas com acentos, verbos conjugados, etc. Encontrei 8 palavras de 13 letras, das quais 4 estão no [dicionário Michaelis Online](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/):

```
deslumbrativo
improfundável
penduricalhos (no dicionário, está no singular, claro)
subclaviforme

1234567890123
```

Talvez exista alguma lista mais completa com palavras maiores, não procurei muito extensivamente.

As seguintes palavras estão na lista filtrada mas não no dicionário que procurei:

```
cumberlandito
obscurantizem
plumbonacrite
sextuplicando
```

Se forem permitidos verbos conjugados (não estão no dicionário, mas plurais também não), tem essas também:

```
centrifugamos
denticularmos
desvincularmo
encruzilhamos
fundilharemos
genuflictamos
```

Comment: Pronto, já perdi :(

Comment: Realmente Jacinto ;-; Mas essa resposta ficou show! Parabéns Molx! E desculpe pelo atraso...

Comment: «Genuflectissem» tem ainda mais letras que «genuflictamos». :)

Answer (score 5):

R E P U B L I C A N O S, 12 letras. Quem dá mais?

E se forem aceites diminuitivos, ainda há:

E X P U R G A D I N H O S  -  13 letras.

Comment: @ANeves Eu interpretei a regra "não valem palavras que não estejam no dicionário" como excluindo diminuitivos.

Answer (score 5):

Não vai dar pra ganhar, mas servem pela curiosidade (no caso da questão não ser considerada off-topic):

[ZAMBUJEIRO](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/zambujeiro)  - 10 LETRAS

[VINCULAÇÕES](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/VINCULA%C3%87%C3%95ES) - 11 LETRAS (O cedilha e o c são diferentes, né? ;-P)

[INSUPORTÁVEL](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/insuport%C3%A1vel)  - 12 LETRAS

Comment: Na verdade você empatou o jogo, já que Diminutivos não são aceitos...

Comment: Ou você coloca alguma palavra com 13 letras ou mais ou você perde... E sim, o cedilha e o c são diferentes.

Comment: @MarcosSartorato, quantas letras tem o teu alfabeto? [23](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto_portugu%C3%AAs)? Ou... `abcçde...` 24? ;)

Answer (score 4):

Se for para votar, elejo "penduricalhos" por ser uma palavra não derivada de outra sem prefixo, sufixo, diminutivo ou aumentativo, apenas o plural de si mesma.