# Qual é o verbo mais comprido da língua portuguesa?

Tags: verbos, conjugações

Quero saber qual o verbo mais comprido da língua portuguesa.

Vi que as desinências com mais caracteres são a primeira pessoa do plural do futuro do pretérito do indicativo e do pretérito imperfeito do subjuntivo; se à desinência somarmos a vogal temática são sete caracteres.

Fazendo a pergunta de outra maneira: Qual o radical verbal mais comprido da língua portuguesa?

| Modo-Tempo | Vogal Temática + Desinência | Comprimento |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Futuro do Pretérito do Indicativo (ou Condicional) | aríamos | 7 |
| Pretérito Imperfeito do Subjuntivo | ássemos | 7 |

Relacionado: [Qual é a maior palavra no Português que não tenha nenhuma letra repetida?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/910)

Comment: Talvez seja *desinstitucionalizar*, que, inclusive, é realmente usada, diferente de *pneumoultramicroscopicossilicovulcanoconiose*. Ou, conjugado: *desinstitucionalizássemos* e *desinstitucionalizaríamos*.

Comment: @Schilive como encontras-te essas palavras?

Comment: bad_coder, vim [nesta lista](https://www.dicio.com.br/maior-palavra-da-lingua-portuguesa/) e vi *desinstitucionalizador* e pensei que daria um verbo, fui no Houaiss, e *voilà*. Bom mesmo seria pegar uma ou algumas listas de palavras da língua portuguesa e filtrar as que terminam em -ar, -er, -ir, e -or. Fá-lo-ei!

Comment: Se _desinstitucionalizar_ conta, concerteza que podemos exagerar mais ainda. _Pseudodesinstitucionalizar_? _Antidesinstitucionalizar_?

Comment: @ANeves Acho que os dois exemplos que dás não formam verbos porque esses prefixos não derivam bases deverbais.

Comment: Além da desinência, deve-se considerar a formação morfológica do verbo. Há sufixos formadores de verbos que, quando somado a um substantivo longo, forma um verbo maior. Consigo pensar em *“-izar”* (como em *“social → socializar”*) e *“-ficar”* (como em *“plano → planificar”*). Obviamente, há afixos (geralmente prefixos) que derivam palavras sem mudar a classe (ou seja, podem formar verbos a partir de verbos), como *“pseudo-”* ou *“super-”*.